# Controlling the number of lines in a dropdown

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

I've noticed that certain dropdowns, despite having e.g. five different options in the set, only display two at a time, which makes scrolling an inconvenience. On the very same form, another dropdown displays three and a half rows and, as far I could see, there's no relation between the number of rows displayed and the placement on the form nor does such a relation exist related to the number of the elements in the option set.

(How) can I control (or at the very least affect) the number of elements displayed in a dropdown? I didn't find any options for that in the settings (format has only the num er of columns to span across).

Comment: Have you played with spacers added below drop down? I think it has something to do with drop down being on the very bottom of section, and crm thinking there's not enough space to show more...

Comment: I concur with @MarioZG

Comment: @Alex If it is so, It's a major inconvenience. What if I need to show e.g. 5 lines in one dropdown but 10 in another? Weird... On the other hand, it's CRM, so perhaps it would be weird if it wasn't inconvenient, hehe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from what I've seen, CRM lets dropdowns lower bound expand until the lower end of the container tab. Because of this, one is forced to add spacers (creating "holes" in the form) when the optionset sits at the bottom...

There doesn't seem to be a way to manipulate this behavior, unless one strays outside supported customizations and goes on manipulating the DOM.